# phpunit Whitelist vs Blacklist

Tags: php, phpunit, lamp

Trying to decide which one would be better suited for my situation. According to the phpunit docs (which are very limited) the whitelist should include all files inside of the directory, but it doesnt seem to be working that way. Does anyone have any suggestions or can point me to a good reference other than the phpunit manual. I am using an XML configuration file. Thanks in advance!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<phpunit>
  <filter>
    <whitelist>
      <directory suffix=".php">/home/ddohr/git/project/</directory>
    <exclude>
      <directory suffix=".php">/home/ddohr/git/project/vendor/</directory>
      <directory suffix=".php">/home/ddohr/git/project/plugins/</directory>
      <directory suffix=".php">/home/ddohr/git/project/test/</directory>
    </exclude>
    </whitelist>
  </filter>
</phpunit>
```

Comment: It works that way for me: [A XML file I'm using now](https://github.com/ircmaxell/PHP-CryptLib/blob/master/test/phpunit.xml.dist)

Comment: Does excluding a file or directory on the whitelist mean that it will still be pulled in if any file "touches" it, it just wont automatically pull all the files in? There are a good amount of files that are in my whitelist directory that dont seem to be pulled in.

Comment: @dave: where's the PHPUnit root tag?  Where's the testsuites tag?  Edit your question to post your full XML file...

Comment: had those tags before and removed them. I don't use test suites, and including and excluding the root tag didn't seem to change anything. Maybe this is my problem?

Comment: @dave: that's not a valid options file.  That's probably why it's failing.  Use the one I linked above as an example and tweak it as necessary...

Comment: Whats not valid? I added the phpunit tags. We dont use test suites we run tests by directory. Thanks!

Comment: *(tip)* https://github.com/gooh/phpunit-schema

Comment: @Dave: see my test cases in that linked project.  I don't use test suites either (not explicit ones anyway).  But you need that tag and the include property to define where your tests are...

Comment: @ircmaxell: I have added the suite chunk to my config with it pointing to my unit test directory. I will rerun my coverage report and post back on how it went. Thanks for all your help ircmaxell and thanks for the tip Gordon!

Comment: reran the coverage and it is still missing multiple directories under the project/lib directory. Does adding a directory add all its sub directories automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** The below no longer works with PHPUnit 3.6 and above. See [Add files to code-coverage white/blacklists in `bootstrap.php` for PHPUnit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8085674/285873) for the new solution.

**Original Answer**

As for the "Whitelist vs Blacklist" question note that they are mutually exclusive, and a whitelist wins out over a blacklist. We use whitelists on our projects since we want 0% coverage reported on classes without tests. Our `bootstrap.php` modules setup the whitelists as that seemed more manageable than placing them in `phpunit.xml` at the time.

For example, the library project's `bootstrap.php` uses `includeDirectoryForCodeCoverage()` to add its source to the whitelist:

```
includeDirectoryForCodeCoverage(MY_LIBRARY_PATH);
```

This is a simple helper for abstracting the actual calls to PHP_CodeCoverage:

```
function includeDirectoryForCodeCoverage($path) {
    PHP_CodeCoverage_Filter::getInstance()
            ->addDirectoryToWhitelist($path);
}

function includeFileForCodeCoverage($path) {
    PHP_CodeCoverage_Filter::getInstance()
            ->addFileToWhitelist($path);
}

function includeFilesForCodeCoverage(array $paths) {
    PHP_CodeCoverage_Filter::getInstance()
            ->addFilesToWhitelist($paths);
}
```

The blacklist is still handy, however. PHPUnit will hide stack trace entries for any code in the blacklisted files. For that reason I added this little gem:

```
function ignoreDirectoryInStackTraces($path) {
    PHP_CodeCoverage_Filter::getInstance()
            ->addDirectoryToBlacklist($path);
}
```

Comment: `PHP_CodeCoverage_Filter::getInstance` has been removed (and non-XML-based setting up of blacklists became a huge pain in the ass) in PHPUnit 3.6.

Comment: See [Add files to code-coverage white/blacklists in `bootstrap.php` for PHPUnit](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8085674/285873) for a solution that works in 3.6.x and above.