# Add files to code-coverage white/blacklists in `bootstrap.php` for PHPUnit

Tags: php, phpunit, code-coverage

PHP_CodeCoverage 1.1 removed the singleton accessor for `PHP_CodeCoverage_Filter` that allowed our PHPUnit `bootstrap.php` files to add directories to the white/blacklists. PHPUnit 3.5 used the blacklist to strip classes from exception stack traces, and CC uses the whitelist to limit tracking. We used both of these features.

How can I get the `PHP_CodeCoverage_Filter` instance that PHPUnit will use from the `bootstrap.php` file?

**Note:** We cannot put these into `phpunit.xml` because the paths are built from environment variables and config files.

**Update:** I see that `PHPUnit_Util_Filter` no longer uses the code coverage blacklist for filtering stack traces. This is fine, and since this class is designed for static access I could add a method to add user directories to the list. It would be an easy change and solve half of this question.

Comment: Does it have to be env AND config files or would be a config file only solution be enough? (Just asking while i look for a way to do that)

Comment: One is purely an environment variable (location of our testing framework). Another is a combination of a `define()` with some static text. The tests are in a directory fairly removed from the source directory so the developer must put the source path into `config.php` which `bootstrap.php` automatically includes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an ugly hack, but it works in PHPUnit 3.6. We already have our own custom test case base class that all others extend. If it doesn't matter when the files get added to the whitelist you could do this using a fake test case just to handle this part.

First, `bootstrap.php` calls BaseTestCase::addXXXToCodeCoverageWhitelist() as many times as necessary to populate an internal array of files to add later. Next, the first test to be executed adds those files to the code coverage filter via the `TestResult`.

```
abstract class BaseTestCase extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    private static $_codeCoverageFiles = array();

    public static function addDirectoryToCodeCoverageWhitelist($path) {
        self::addFilesToCodeCoverageWhitelist(self::getFilesForDirectory($path));
    }

    public static function addFileToCodeCoverageWhitelist($path) {
        self::addFilesToCodeCoverageWhitelist(array($path));
    }

    public static function addFilesToCodeCoverageWhitelist(array $paths) {
        self::$_codeCoverageFiles = array_merge(self::$_codeCoverageFiles, $paths);
    }

    public static function getFilesForDirectory($path) {
        $facade = new File_Iterator_Facade;
        return $facade->getFilesAsArray($path, '.php');
    }

    private static function setCodeCoverageWhitelist(PHP_CodeCoverage $coverage = null) {
        if ($coverage && self::$_codeCoverageFiles) {
            $coverage->setProcessUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist(true); // pick your poison
            $coverage->filter()->addFilesToWhitelist(self::$_codeCoverageFiles);
            self::$_codeCoverageFiles = array();
        }
    }

    public function runBare() {
        self::setCodeCoverageWhitelist($this->getTestResultObject()->getCodeCoverage());
        parent::runBare();
    }
}
```

**Update:** For anyone that used the blacklist to keep framework classes from showing up in assertion failure stack traces as we did, add the following methods to the above class and call them from your `bootstrap.php`. This requires `setAccessible()` from PHP 5.3.

```
    public static function ignoreDirectoryInStackTraces($path) {
        ignoreFilesInStackTraces(self::getFilesForDirectory($path));
    }

    public static function ignoreFileInStackTraces($path) {
        ignoreFilesInStackTraces(array($path));
    }

    public static function ignoreFilesInStackTraces($files) {
        static $reflector = null;
        if (!$reflector) {
            PHPUnit_Util_GlobalState::phpunitFiles();
            $reflector = new ReflectionProperty('PHPUnit_Util_GlobalState', 'phpunitFiles');
            $reflector->setAccessible(true);
        }
        $map = $reflector->getValue();
        foreach ($files as $file) {
            $map[$file] = $file;
        }
        $reflector->setValue($map);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing! (What does 'getFilesForDirectory' do here? I assume just what the function states but I don't see where it comes from)

Comment: Oops, good catch. I've added it above. Yes, it does exactly what the name says. :) Thanks!

Comment: I added the methods that allow you to remove classes from assertion failure stack traces. This is useful for your custom assertions and base test case classes.

Answer (score 2):

I've asked Sebastian about it and he confirmed that there is no way to programmatically access CodeCoverage_Filter with PHPUnit 3.6.

My suggestion would be to also create the phpunit.xml dynamically by having a template and then filling adding the needed `<directory>` nodes after the configuration file was filled out.

Maybe there will be a way to inject PHP_CodeCoverage[_Filter] objects by subclassing the test runner in the future though.

Comment: I noticed the (new?) class `PHPUnit_Util_GlobalState` this morning. This would make a *great* place to store the current runner which could provide access to the other PHPUnit objects in play.

Comment: @DavidHarkness While `PHPUnit_Util_GlobalState` is there do deal with the global application state (--backup globals) I've suggested something like that to Sebastian yesterday. A way to get access to the needed objects in the bootstrap f.e. He said he was thinking about a way of injection those objects into a custom test runner.. both options might work but for now with 3.6 there sadly is no direct solution in sight